# How to render html table with multiple rowspan using multidimensional array - Salesforce

Tags: javascript, html, css, salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I am pulling back data from an Apex class into an LWC. The data resembles the following structure:

```
[
    {
        questionId: 1,
        responses: [{
            responseId: 11,
            responseText: 'lorem ipsom',
            actions: [
                {
                    actionId: 111,
                    actionTitle: 'dummy title 1'
                },
                {
                    actionId: 112,
                    actionTitle: 'dummy title 2'
                }
            ]
    },
    {
        questionId: 2,
        responses: [
            {
                responseId: 22,
                responseText: 'lorem ipsum text 2',
                actions: [
                    {
                        actionId: 221
                        actionTitle: 'dummy title 3'
                    }
                }]
            },
            {
                responseId: 23,
                responseText: 'lore ipsum text 3'
                actions: [
                    {
                        actionId: 331,
                        actionTitle: 'dummy title 4'
                    }
                ]
            }
                
        ]
    }
]
```

A question could have multiple responses and a response could have multiple actions.

I need to render this data in a html table that should resemble the following:

[Table result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMDWe.png)

I have previously tried using the rowspan attribute in html. I also tried creating multiple sub tables in each <td> in the table. This worked to an extent however the styling was misaligned. I a trying to find the cleanest way to have this done.